# Hadoop performance modeling

Tags: performance, hadoop, modeling

I am working on Hadoop performance modeling. Hadoop has 200+ parameters so setting them manually is not possible. So often we run our hadoop jobs with default parameter value(like using default value io.sort.mb, io.sort.record.percent, mapred.output.compress etc). But using default parameter value gives us sub optimal performance. There is some work done in this area by Herodotos Herodotou (http://www.cs.duke.edu/starfish/files/vldb11-job-optimization.pdf) to improve performance. But i have following doubt in their work --

1. They are fixing the value of parameters at the job start time( according to  proportionality assumption of data) for all the phases( read, map, collect etc.) of MapReduce job. Can we set different value of these parameters for each phase at run time according to run time environment( like cluster configuration, underling file system etc.), by changing Hadoop configuration log files of a particular node to get optimal performance from a node ?
2. They are using white box model for Hadoop core  are they still applicable for
   current Hadoop ( http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.0940.pdf) ?

Comment: Priyan, I'm not voting to close this question because I don't know enough about Hadoop to know whether it's a good question, but it looks like (a) you have not given enough detail about what you've tried and what you're trying to do, and (b) you're asking too broad of a question. (#1 looks like you want documentation pages, not an answer to a question.)  I suggest that you edit your question to make it more specific.  Others will probably vote to close it.

Comment: Now, is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, good.  I think that the edits are what allowed Ashrith to answer.  (#2 is still not very clear to me, if you mean the general-purpose concept of a white box model.  If there's a Hadoop-specific white box model concept, then maybe #2 *is* clear.  As I said, I don't know Hadoop.  But if Ashrith answers #1, and you still have questions about #2, maybe you should post a separate Stackoverflow question about #2.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you couldn't dynamically change MapReduce parameters per job per node.

#### Configuring set of nodes

Rather what you could do is change the configuration parameters per node statically in the configuration files (generally located in `/etc/hadoop/conf`), so that you could take the most out of your cluster with different h/w configurations.

Example: Assume you have 20 worker nodes with different hardware configurations like:

- 10 with configuration of 128GB RAM, 24 Cores
- 10 with configuration of 64GB RAM, 12 Cores

In that case you would want to configure each of identical servers to take most out of the hardware for example, you would want to run more child tasks (mappers & reducers) on worker nodes with more RAM and Cores, for example:

- Nodes with 128GB RAM, 24 Cores => 36 worker tasks (mappers + reducers), JVM heap for each worker task would be around 3GB.
- Nodes with 64GB RAM, 12 Cores => 18 worker tasks (mappers + reducers), JVM heap for each worker task would be around 3GB.

So, you would want to configure the set of nodes respectively with appropriate parameters.

#### Using ToolRunner to pass configuration parameters dynamically to a Job:

Also, you could dynamically change the MapReduce job parameters per job but these parameters would be applied to the entire cluster not just to a set of nodes. Provided your MapReduce job driver extends [ToolRunner](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/ToolRunner.html).

**ToolRunner** allows you to parse [generic hadoop command line arguments](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#Generic_Options). You'll be able to pass MapReduce configuration parameters using `-D property.name=property.value`.

You can pretty much pass almost all hadoop parameters dynamically to a job. But most *commonly* passed MapReduce configuration parameters dynamically to a job are:

- `mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb`
- `mapreduce.map.speculative`
- `mapreduce.job.reduces`
- `mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor`
- `mapreduce.map.output.compress`
- `mapreduce.map.outout.compress.codec`
- `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb`
- `mapreduce.map.memory.mb`

Here is an example `terasort` job passing lots of parameters dynamically per job:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar tearsort \     
  -Ddfs.replication=1 -Dmapreduce.task.io.sort.mb=500 \     
  -Dmapreduce.map.sort.splill.percent=0.9 \     
  -Dmapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies=10 \     
  -Dmapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent=0.1 \     
  -Dmapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent=0.95 \     
  -Dmapreduce.reduce.input.buffer.percent=0.95 \     
  -Dmapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent=0.95 \     
  -Dmapreduce.reduce.merge.inmem.threshold=0 \     
  -Dmapreduce.job.speculative.speculativecap=0.05 \     
  -Dmapreduce.map.speculative=false \     
  -Dmapreduce.map.reduce.speculative=false \
   -Dmapreduce.job.jvm.numtasks=-1 \
  -Dmapreduce.job.reduces=84 \
   -Dmapreduce.task.io.sort.factor=100 \     
  -Dmapreduce.map.output.compress=true \
   -Dmapreduce.map.outout.compress.codec=\         
    org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \     
  -Dmapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps=0.4 \     
  -Dmapreduce.reduce.merge.memtomem.enabled=fasle \     
  -Dmapreduce.reduce.memory.totalbytes=12348030976 \     
  -Dmapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=12288 \
   -Dmapreduce.reduce.java.opts=“-Xms11776m -Xmx11776m \       
    -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode \       
    -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4” \
   -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096 \
   -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=“-Xmx1356m” \     
  /terasort-input /terasort-output
```

Comment: I want to know more on your second point "Rather what you could do ......."     means if you will not specify  at job submission time then Hadoop will use local node configuration logs for accessing parameter value at job execution time and you can modify these log files using bash script at run time according to suggestion given by  some node performance model . One more thing, Does Hadoop access these parameter values form log for each phase of job or just one time per job on a node ?

Comment: Hadoop daemons reads the properties from the configuration lines only once that is while startup, hence if you have changed the parameters in the configuration files you have to restart the daemons to force them read new configuration parameters.

Comment: OK, Is there any way for changing parameters( parameters that are phase independent ) in each phase( phase like read, map, collect spill, etc.) because if i will stop daemons running on  a node it will not resume computation ( and it will redo all the phases  and Hadoop may start speculative execution) and performance will degrade.

Comment: One way to override the parameters per job is through setting them in the job's driver class or pass in from command line like shown above using ToolRunner.

Comment: OK, But these phase(phase like read, map, collect spill, etc.) exists within  in one job.

Comment: I am not sure if you could change the configuration parameters per phase.